# How do I prove a lower bound on the number of operations for a nested forloop

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Below I attempt to show a lower bound on the number of additions the algorithm performs. Please tell me if my analysis is correct or not.

Here is an inefficient algorithm for computing the consecutive sum of all i,j i < j, for an array A with n elements

```
for i=1 to n
  for j = i+1 to n
    B[i,j] = 0
    for i < j: 
      B[i,j] += A[i,j]
return B
```

I am arguing that this algorithm will require at least n^3 operations. 
**Here is my argument:**

1. n iterations from outer forloop
2. If i = n\2 then the inner forloop will iterate at least n/2 times
3. if i=n/2 and j=n then it will take at least n/2 additions to sum up the elements from i to j

Thus the algorithm preforms n * n/2 * n/2 = (n^3)/4 operations.

Comment: You should write out how to sum the elements from i to j, since there are fast ways and slow ways.

Comment: Assume its linear time algorithm. Updated the code anyway.

Comment: Looks like there must be a typo: The innermost loop runs forever because i and j don't change in the body of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's close, but your proof doesn't quite prove what you want to.  You said:

> 1. n iterations from outer forloop

Ok, so at least Ω(n)

> 2. If i = n\2 then the inner forloop will iterate at least n/2 times

Sure, but i = n/2 for only one iteration, so this proves only n/2 iterations in total... again at least Ω(n)

> 3. if i=n/2 and j=n then it will take at least n/2 additions to sum up the elements from i to j

Right, but again those conditions only happen once, so this only proves Ω(n) again.

The proof you are going for is like this:

1. There are at least **n/2-1** iterations of the outer loop where **i < n/2**
2. In each of those iterations, **n-i >= n/2**, and the inner loop runs for that many iterations, so there be at least **(n/2)(n/2 - 1)** iterations of the inner loop.
3. At least half of the inner loop iterations -- specifically at least **(n/4)(n/2 - 1) - 1** of them -- sum over at least **n/4** elements and therefore require **n/4 - 1** additions.

So there are at least **( (n/4)(n/2-1) - 1 )(n/4 - 1)** additions, and that is in **Ω(n^3)**

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to settle for a lower bound. There's an exact solution.

Go ahead and write a little program that prints the exact number of additions for the the first few values of `n`.

Then Google for that series of values.  You'll find it's a well-known series with a closed form expression.

Comment: that seems like cheating haha just kidding. I'm aware this is possibility but it seems like it just making life harder on yourself

Comment: I did it. It took about 6 minutes working in C. Probably would have been 3 in Python, but I didn't have access at the moment. The solution is exact. Why settle for Ω() and O() when you can easily get the exact answer? If you are interested in execution at the level of individual instructions, constant factors probably matter ... a lot. @MathyewDMcGlaweflin